# Tools / Scripts for importing csv to db table

Tags: php, csv

In tried importing a csv into a table using phpMyAdmin and I'm getting permission errors so I'm looking for any php scripts available around that I can use.

What scripts are available? Can ane point to any free one's?

Comment: Can you not use the console to load the data? http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/load-data.html

Comment: Tried to do it from phpmyadmin already and I get permission denied so I've given up that and I'm trying to find a php script to do it

Comment: If you log into the console but don't have permissions to add data to the table, have you checked the user permissions for the user/pass that you are using to connect to the MySQL server? Has that user got permissions to insert data to that table?

Comment: Yes, it's the main user so it's supposed to have permissions to do anything

Answer (score 1):

```
fgetcsv is the php function you should use.
```

For details [see here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.fgetcsv.php).

Sample code here..

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("test.csv", "r")) !== FALSE) {
  while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    echo "<p> $num fields in line $row: <br /></p>\n";
    $row++;
    for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
        // write insert query here
        echo $data[$c] . "<br />\n";
    }
  }
  fclose($handle);
 }
```

Thanks.